# What is known about the irrationality of ratios and products of logarithms of integers?

Tags: transcendental-number-theory, irrational-numbers

Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive natural numbers such that $\{a,b\} \neq \{c,d\}$ and such that none are perfect powers. Is it true that

$$\frac{\log a \log b}{\log c \log d} \notin \mathbb{Q} ?$$

The theorems of transcendental number theory such as the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem say a fair amount about when the transcendence and irrationality of linear combinations of log's of natural numbers, but questions of this form seem to require knowledge about linear combinations of products of logs of natural numbers. What, if anything, is known here?

Even less ambitiously, can one show that there is no non-trivial solutions to expressions such as
$$ \frac{a b \log c \log d} {cd\log a \log b } =1$$
in the natural numbers?

Comment: A minor MathJAX note:  I think you should write that out as
$$\frac{\log a \log b}{\log c \log d} \not\in \mathbb{Q},$$
@MarkLewko?

Comment: Isn't it already hard to say anything about $\log2\log3$?